# Cómo insertar una imagen en una celda especifica en un datagrid

Tags: c#, visual, properties

soy nuevo en la programación, y no entiendo mucho del tema, espero me puedan ayudar.
Estoy intentando ingresar una imagen en una celda especifica en un data grid, el problema es cuando escribo la sentencia Properties.Resources, me arroja un error diciendo que el nombre properties no existe en el contexto actual.
Este es mi código

```
private void dgvdata_CellPainting(object sender, 
DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
 
 ir (e.RowIndex < 0)
     return;

     if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) {

    e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);

    var w = properties.icons8_cancelar_color_16.Width;
    var h = Properties.Resources.cancelar.Height;
    var x = e.CellBounds.Left + (e.CellBounds.Width - w) / 2;
    var y = e.CellBounds.Top + (e.CellBounds.Height - h) / 2;

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.icons8_cancelar_color_16, new Rectangle(x, y, w, h));
    e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!